# What's the fastest way to convert a byte array to a hex string in C++?

Tags: c++

There are a lot of different ways to convert a byte array to a hex string.  What is the fastest way?

- [C-style sprintf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6357065/10247)
- [C-style lookups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17147874/10247)
- [C++-style stringstream](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9893603/10247)

There are possibly more.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9893603/2970947) answer scored highly the last time

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Testing over 100,000 iterations found:

1. the lookups solution took 63 ms.
2. the sprintf solution took 827 ms (~10x more than #1).
3. the stringstream solution took 1684 ms (~25x more than #1).

All results from my own test system.

This is probably a surprise to no one very familiar with C and C++ but given the number of different approaches available for solving this problem, having a Q&A on the approach with the best performance could be useful for people less familiar with C/C++.

Comment: Ugh, you could just edit your question.