# Why is ParseFromString() not producing an output in my application using protobuf?

Tags: c++, networking, protocol-buffers

I currently have a `*.cpp` file where I import the needed `*.proto.h` file and instantiate an object based on one of the messages(Heartbeat) from my `*.proto` file. My goal is to use the `set_value()`, `SerializeToString()`, and `ParseFromString()`.I've had success accomplishing the first two tasks. When using `ParseFromString()` not output is produced to the screen. I'm pretty new to `protobufs` so there may be something I'm overlooking. This is my code.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "cpnt.pb.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    wombat::HeartBeat h;

    string m;
    string t;
    string v;

    h.set_value(1);
    v = h.SerializeToString(&m);
    t  = h.ParseFromString(v);

    cout << "\n The message received is:" << h.value();
    cout << "\n The binary data stored in v is:" << v;
    cout << "\n The parsed data stored in t is:" << t <<::endl;
    return 0;

}
```

And this is a printout of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You misunderstood how `SerializeToString` works. `h.SerializeToString(&m);` serializes `h` and stores the result in `m`. `h.ParseFromString(v);` parsed from the string `v` to set members of `h`. Hence it should be

```
h.set_value(1);
h.SerializeToString(&m);
h.ParseFromString(m);
```

Both functions retun a `bool`, but I admit that I didn't find what it is good for in the documentation. Probably to signal an error.

Comment: any idea on how to see the parsed message? I tried storing h.ParseFromString(m) to a variable and printing to the screen and it just returns binary

Comment: @TellrellWhite `std::cout << m;` ?

Comment: @TellrellWhite That is because it is binary. It is not a text string, I have never understood why these functions are called this way when the use/produce an array of bytes. Best output the results as hex.

Comment: @Bart it took me a week of debugging before I realized that the seralized string can contain null terminators in the middle. Its really not nice to call it "string"

Comment: @Bart How exactly do you output in hex. And will I be able to see the message?

Comment: @TellrellWhite You can convert it using `StringStream` objects: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9893497/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-hexadecimal-string-in-c/27803436. You will be able to see the serialized message as hex format. So not the actual data you set in it but the serialized version of it.

Comment: `ParseFromString` returns true if the parsing has succeeded, false if not. It's meant for error checking. The `FromString`/`ToString` is somewhat confusing, but it just means that the functions deal with `std::string`, as opposed to [other methods](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.message_lite#parsing) like `ParseFromCodedStream` and `ParseFromArray`. It's important to note that it's perfectly valid for an `std::string` to contain null bytes.

Comment: If you just want to see the values, you probably want `std::cout << h.DebugString()`.